# Using sed to sanitize files

Tags: linux, sed

I am using sed to sanitize backups by removing all the lines before the word "Saved".  This is working well:

```
sed '1,/Saved/d' filename_20210112_184230 > filename_20210112_184230_sanitized
```

My question is the first part of each file "filename" is a fixed value, however the remainder of the name is a dynamic value consisting of date and time.  I have two questions:

1. Is there a way I can use a wild card in my statement so it will match anything starting "filename".
2. is there a way I can omit the creation of a new file if it exists?

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `find` and a loop instead of wildcards in the `sed` command.

Comment: I have actually found a way to do this, but now my question is there any way to match a portion of the input filename to the output filename.  so for example I am modifying everything starting "test1" and there are multiple filenames test1_1, test1_2.  Is there anyway to copy the 1_1 and 1_2 over to the output filename?

Comment: "Omit the creation of a new file if it exists" -> Do you mean to prevent overwriting the `_sanitized` file if it already exists?

Comment: Yes, there is, if you use a loop with `find` like I said.

Comment: @lquin1978 alternatively to find, you may want to use a for-loop in your shell and iterate over the files.

Comment: @lquin1978 Please [edit] your question instead of adding information or new requirements in comments. Show your (incomplete) solution, then we can answer the question about constructing the output file name from the input file name without guessing.